# web-based user password reset

Tags: server, password, user-management, password-recovery

I am configuring a server for a small group of users.
The server runs a ftp server, email-server and wordpress.

I would like to have a webbased password recovery that will send an email to a pre-determined email-adress of a user, if that user wants to reset his/her user-password.

Example:

- Tim wants to login to the FTP-server
- Tim forgot his password
- Tim goes to "https://password.[servername].nl
- Tim gets a reset mail on his registrered email adress with a link
- Tim is prompted to a web-based environment where he can fill in a new password.

Is this kind of service available for Ubuntu server?

Comment: Programming platforms like Laravel (PHP) offer this right out of the box, and it is not a wheel that you want to reinvent. However, this is not an Ubuntu question.

Comment: why not? i thought it would be because it is about Ubuntu user management and groups | asking if there any methods of password recovery this way.

Comment: Sounds like a job for python and flask.. :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595340/changing-linux-username-or-password-with-python-script

Comment: Or bash
https://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/34017-automation-script-password-reset.html

Comment: However from a admin point of view.. setting up ubuntu to use LDAP for user authentication has advantages because you only have a single database in your entire network for all machines..     This also means you can reset and update passwords from a single point.

https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/onprem-auth

Comment: Personaly I would go with SSH and private/public keys